# How do I verify the integrity of my installation?

Tags: xubuntu, system-installation

I installed a fresh Xubuntu 13.10, and at the end of the installation, it requested a restart. Just before the restart, a fatal error or something occurred. Is there an event log I can check to make sure my installation is ok? There wasn't enough time to read the fatal error.

**How do I verify the integrity of my installation?**

- So following up on a possibly bad installation -- it's asking me to remove many many packages, including `xubuntu-desktop` if I want to install `ndiswrapper`. Is that a flag telling me the installation was bad?
- Something was definitely wrong with my installation. I did a fresh install again, and everything seems to be fine. The question still holds though ^